# Rails : what rails fuzzy method/gem/plugin use to search in a 1 million records database table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sphinx, fuzzy-search

I own a ~1 million records MySQL table.
I will need soon to add search in my Rails 3.x app. I want the search to be fuzzy.

Actually, I use a plugin (rails-fuzzy-search) for another table but it's only 3000 records.
This plugin create trigrams in another table (25000 trigrams for the 3000 records table).

Well, I can't use this method for my 1 million records table else my trigrams table will be maybe 100 millions records !

I see some gems:

- https://github.com/seamusabshere/fuzzy_match
- https://github.com/kiyoka/fuzzy-string-match
- Or the use of Sphinx and Thinking Sphinx + addons.

I don't know what is the best solution for better performances.

The search will be set for two fields of my table.

Answer (score 2):

some searching around revealed [fuzzily](http://dec0de.me/2012/10/fuzzily-released/) gem:

> Anecdotical benchmark: against our whole Geonames-derived table of
>   locations (3.2M records, about 1GB of data), on my development machine
>   (a 2011 MacBook Pro)
>
> searching for the top 10 matching records takes 6ms ±1 preparing the
>   index for all records takes about 10min the DB query overhead when
>   changing a record is at 3ms ±2 the memory overhead (footprint of the
>   trigrams table index) is about 300MB

Also, check out [Solr and Sunspot](http://johntwang.com/blog/2011/09/05/Fuzzy-and-Document-Searching-with-WebSolr-and-Heroku/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database, you may be able to enable database-specific features to achieve some "fuzzy matching" (whatever that means exactly).

**MySQL** has "Natural Language Mode", which is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590792/mysql-fulltext-index-what-is-natural-language-mode/77154793).

This is fairly easy to implement. First add an index in a migration like so:

```rb
add_index :products, [:name, :description], type: :fulltext, name: :fulltext_index_products_on_name_and_description
```

Then you can use the MATCH clause in your query like so:

```rb
scope :search, ->(query) {
  where("MATCH (products.name, products.description) AGAINST (? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)", query)
  # MySQL should sort by relevance, so make sure not to override this with your own order clause.
}
```

Be aware you may get unexpected results testing on a small dataset, it's best to try it with full data. You may also find "BOOLEAN MODE" worth looking into.